# Why was this offensive flag declined?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270297) (deleted now so only 10k+ can see it). When it was first posted, it had a link to a porn site, so I flagged it. It was then edited out by the user later. So was the flag declined because the user edited out the offensive material after I flagged it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it was a subtly hidden link which is probably why it didn't get caught. You did the right thing, but sometimes mods get things wrong.

Comment: Didn't help that it got edited shortly thereafter.  Not sure if it was an honest mistake or not.

Comment: @Frank The asker posted the link to the GTA download, which they turned into a link to a porn site.  They changed it shortly after someone called them out on it, and then played dumb. It definitely wasn't a mistake.

Comment: @Wipqozn Mm.  I dunno.  I'm generally the first on the list to decry bad behaviour, but this isn't hitting my bad faith filters.

Comment: @Frank Yeah, I wasn't sure at first either, but there's no way it was a mistake. For it to have been a mistake they would have needed to posted the link to the GTA site, then stopped typing up their question part way through to,uh, "take a break", on the porn site, copied the home page URL into their clip board for some reason, then come back to finish typing their question, accidentally highlight the GTA link text and then paste in the home page porn link, and save the question.

Comment: @Wipqozn Seems like an awful lot of effort to go to.  I guess the disparity between the question quality, and the misleading link just didn't strike me as trolling.  I do agree that the order of operations required for it to be a mistake is a bit much, though.